# Java ArrayList break remove

Tags: java, arraylist

I was trying to write a code that would remove all zeros before the first non-zero element in an integer ArrayList, scanned from index 0. However, the code keeps on removing a fixed no. of zeros after the first non-zero element. can anybody figure out why?(Sorry if format of question posted is not ideal. this is my first time.)
For the following code, the intended output was `[2 0 0 0 0 0]`, but the output received was `[2 0 0]`

```
class Zeroeliminator {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList < Integer > arr = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
        arr.add(0); // A
        arr.add(2);
        for (int i = 2; i < 7; i++)
            arr.add(0);
        System.out.println(arr.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            if (arr.get(i) != 0) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(arr.get(i));
            arr.remove(i);
        }
        System.out.println(arr.size());
        ListIterator < Integer > itr = arr.listIterator(0);
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(itr.next() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you remove an element, all the elements following shift along by 1...

Comment: you want to remove all zeros before or after the first non zero element ?

Comment: Your problem comes from the fact that you're trying to mutate the array while iterating through it (see Eran's explanation below). Here is a friendly advice: do NOT do that. Instead, keep track of the items you're supposed to remove and then remove all of them after you're done iterating the array (see Andy's answer).

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your code is that when you remove an element, all of the elements after it are shifted down by one. So, the state of one iteration looks like this:

```
arr=[0 2 0 0], i = 0
         // Remove element i
arr=[2 0 0], i = 0
         // Increment i
arr=[2 0 0], i = 1
```

On the next iteration, you'll check for i = 1, and ignore the fact there was a 2 there, because you never read its value.

You can fix this by decrementing `i` each time you remove an element. But you don't then need `i` at all, because you're removing the list prefix. Instead, you could just use:

```
while (!arr.isEmpty() && list.get(0) == 0) {
  arr.remove(0);
}
```

---

A better (more efficient) approach to this is to scan through the list first to find the first non-zero element, and then delete the preceding elements in one go:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < arr.size() && arr.get(i) == 0) {
  i++;
}
arr.subList(0, i).clear();
```

Removing 1 element from the front of an ArrayList is O(size), because all of the other elements have to be shifted down by one; so removing multiple elements is O(#removed * size).

The approach using sublist does all of the shifts in one go, so it is O(size).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply(more so for the different approach)! yeah I forgot that remove() decreases indices of all successive elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decrement `i` when you remove an element, since the indices of the `ArrayList` elements following the removed element are decremented.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
{
    if(arr.get(i) != 0){
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(arr.get(i));
    arr.remove(i);   
    i--;   
}
```

Comment: could possibly generate `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` but not in this example i guess

Comment: I don't see any way this code can cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Brain fart, it can't cause it